# JQuery doesn't handle dynamic events with .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

On a webpage, when you click a link, the content of that page is fetched using the .load function. If nothing is found, then nothing happens.
The issue now is that if you go from one page to the next, and then back again, the code doesn't work.

Its a lot easier to go to my test site - http://joshblease.co.uk/JQuery/

1. Click on the orange link "Page"
2. Click on the header link "Index"
3. Now click on the orange "Page" link again

The page refreshes and I do not know why?

Edit: I am using Chrome to test this at the moment

Edit: My Code

```
function JLoad (url, elem, type) {
    if(type != "ext"){
        var $link = elem;
        var uri = url + ' #content';
        $("#content").load(uri, {'body_only': '1'}, function(response, status, xhr){
            if (status != "error") {
                if (window.history && window.history.pushState){
                    window.history.pushState({}, 'JoshBlease Test', url);
                }else{
                        window.location.hash='!/'+url;
                }
                if(type == "menu"){
                    $("a").removeClass("active");
                    $link.addClass("active");
                }
            }else{
                if(type == "menu"){
                    var linkText = $link.text();
                    $link.fadeOut(function(){$link.addClass("notFound").text("404 Error")}).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(function(){$link.removeClass("notFound").text(linkText)}).fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This is in the header of the pages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function(event) {
        console.log("Click");
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href").replace('./', '');
        JLoad(url, $(this), $(this).attr("type"));
        return false;
    });
});
```

The Link being used:

```
<a href="page.php" type="content">Page</a>
```

Comment: Can you paste your jQuery code here?

Comment: @pvnarula I have done now

Comment: @pvnarula, I replace "on" with "live" and it worked! Any idea why and/or how I can use "on" so I can be up to date with JQuery?

Comment: @pvnarula So judging by your answer, there is no way to manipulate my code to work with the "on" function?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but by using an old version of JQuery, I replaced the "on" event with "live". It now seems to work?

Comment: yes, it is fine. "live" is deprecated in new version but will work with older version of jQuery. New version supports "on".